# How to add a html bold <b> and break <br> in the jsf tags

Tags: jsf

**In Property file**

```
msg_profile = <b> profile1: </b> <br> Set profile
```

I have given bold and break html tags between Profile1 and Set profile in above property.

**Bean**

```
private List<SelectItem> profiles;
this.profiles.add(new SelectItem(new Integer(0), MessageFactory.getString(context, "msg_profile")));
```

**xhtml file**

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="profiles" layout="pageDirection" value="#{bean.selectedProfile}" style="font-size:12px;">
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.profiles}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>                                      
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I am expecting out put is

'Profile1:' in bold
'Set Profile' in new line

Answer (score 0):

You should use `itemLabel` and `itemValue` as shown in this example (stolen from Mojarra doc). I think your code doesn't work because you have no `var`, `itemLabel` and `itemValue` attribute set:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{select05NoSelection.hobbitList}"
                 var="n"
                 itemValue="#{n}"
                 itemLabel="#{n.bio}"
                 itemDescription="#{n.description}"
                 itemDisabled="#{n.disabled}"
                 itemLabelEscaped="true"
                 noSelectionValue="#{select05NoSelection.hobbitList[0]}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Handy,                                                                 private List<SelectItem> profiles;

Comment: @venkat: Still more to come? Of course you have to adapt the example.

Comment: Hi Handy,                                                          I writeen my code in below                                                                    msg_property=<b>Profile</> <br> set values                                                                                                                             private List<SelectItem> profiles;                         this.profiles.add(new SelectItem(new Integer(0), MessageFactory.getString(context, "msg_propertyvl")));

Comment: <h:selectOneRadio id="profiles" layout="pageDirection" value="#{bean.selectedProfile}" style="font-size:12px;">
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.profiles}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>                                      
</h:selectOneRadio>

Comment: Did you get my requirement? I am loading values form property file. and filled in bean list.

Comment: @venkat: Please add relevant code to your *question* and not in a comment. It's hard to read inside a comment.

Comment: Hi Handy, Can you please look into my complete requirement?

Comment: @venkat Is your list filled correctly in backing bean. Did you verify that? Your bean snippet is quite short. I cannot see where (which method) the item list is filled.

Comment: Yes it is correct. I am filling list when initialize the bean in set method.

Comment: @venkat: Fill the list in the set method?  Which set method? Could you add getter and setter of `List<SelectItem> profiles`?

Comment: Hi Handy, problem with not set and get methods. Problem is itemLabelEscaped="false" is not working. I have written in code <f:selectItems value="#{bean.profiles}" itemLabelEscaped="false"/>